# How to delete a specific array item with a button?

Tags: php

So I have this foreach loop that displays all the products and products information. I want to have a delete button for each item.

```php
        <?php
        function test($par){
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$par]);
        }
        if(array_key_exists('test',$_POST)){
            test($i);
         }
         $i = 0;
            foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as list ($weight,$size,$qty,$price)) {
            echo "<div class='cartitems'>";
            echo "<h2>".$weight."</h2>";
            echo "<h2>".$size."</h2>";
            echo "<h2>".$qty."</h2>";
            echo "<h2>".$price."</h2>";
            echo "<form method='post'><input type='submit' name='test'/></form>";
            echo "</div>";
            $i++;
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Why doesn't the cart include a product ID? When the user checks out, how do you know what products they're purchasing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could append this to your foreach loop:

```
echo "<a href='YOUR_DELETE_PAGE.php?delete_id={$id}'>Delete</a>"
```

Having add the line above, you will have to pass the id of the product you want to delete into the `$_SESSION['cart']`.

Finally, in your `YOUR_DELETE_PAGE.php`, you can do this:

```
if (isset($_GET['delete_id']) {
   $item_id = $_GET['delete_id'];
   $item = array_search($_GET['delete_id'], array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'id'));
   if ($item !== false) {
      unset($_SESSION['cart'][$item]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Where does `$id` come from?

Comment: `$_SESSION['cart']` is a 2-dimensional array, not an array of IDs. `array_search()` won't work.

Comment: Like i said, he / she needs to pass the id of the product that needs to be deleted into the $_SESSION['cart']. That can be replaced with whatever variable name was used.

Comment: There is no ID in his cart. Look at the `foreach` loop that's showing ths shopping cart.

Comment: I said he have to add ID to his cart. That's the only way my answer can work for him.  I didn't assume that he have ID in his cart.

Comment: OK, even if he does that, `array_search()` won't work the way you've shown.

Comment: It would need to be `array_search($_GET['delete_id'], array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'id'))`

Comment: Also, `if ($item)` should be `if ($item !== false)`. Otherwise you won't be able to delete the first item in the cart.

Comment: Oh, okay. I will update my code. Since i never tested the code, i wouldn't know lol.

Comment: `array_column($_SESSION['cart'], $item_id)` should be `array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'id')`